# Methods "runtime" and "system-clock" always return 0.1

Tags: scheme, lisp, mit-scheme

According to manual, methods `runtime` and `system-clock` return:

> the amount of process time, in seconds, that has elapsed since Scheme was
>   started.

However, calling them in REPL always return value 0.1:

```
1 ]=> (runtime)
;Value: .01
1 ]=> (system-clock)
;Value: .01
```

Any ideas what is happening here?

`mit-scheme` version:

```
Release 9.1.1 || Microcode 15.3 || Runtime 15.7 || SF 4.41 || LIAR/x86-64 4.118
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These procedures don't give you the real time that has elapsed since you started scheme but **the time it has taken to process scheme code**, not including system calls. Thus you have evaluated two expressions that have taken very short time and the time you are looking at the prompt or writing code is not included since it doesn't process anything when it is waiting for a line of input.

The code below takes almost 2 seconds to complete and sure enough it shows that it has been working for `1.49`s.

```
(begin
  (define (fib n)
    (if (< n 2)
        n
        (+ (fib (- n 1)) (fib (- n 2)))))

  (fib 30)
  (system-clock))
; ==> 1.49
```

Comment: Huh, I understood "process time" as "time elapsed since system process was started" not "processing time". Thanks for the clarification.